# npm install formidable does not work in node 0.10

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am doing the tutorials in **[The Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)** and I cannot install `formidable` because of a version error.  Here's the error.  I seem to get this error with or without using `sudo` and `@latest`.

```
npm install formidable@latest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm WARN engine formidable@1.0.13: wanted: {"node":"<0.9.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.0","npm":"1.2.14"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [readme.md in github](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/Readme.md) and it will show the npm install command as well as the git clone command which should work if npm install fails.

```
git clone git://github.com/felixge/node-formidable.git formidable
```

Answer (score 4):

The error means exactly what's stated, the module is expecting a Node version before 0.9.0 and your current version is 0.10.0.

```
wanted: {"node":"<0.9.0"}
current: {"node":"v0.10.0","npm":"1.2.14"}
```

An easy solution to this would be using an older version of Node, which you can easily get from the Node repository.

You can also use [*n*](https://github.com/visionmedia/n), which allows you to easily switch between or install multiple node binaries.

```
npm install -g n
n 0.8.9
//installs node version 0.8.9
```

If you won't need the binary later, you can remove it easily.

```
n rm 0.8.9
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I can leave the sarcasm. I can read. Anywho, this is great info, but I'm not about to downgrade node just for a tutorial. All that said, +1, @hexacyanide.

Comment: Oh - just noticed that you answered your own question. If it solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Cool. I made it community wiki, just trying to help out anyone else who gets this issue with the tutorial. PEACE

Answer (score 1):

try a fork of formidable that supposedly supported 0.10.x:

https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem with my node v0.10.25 after running the below code.

```
> npm install formidable@latest

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
```

I change the instruction to

```
> npm install formidable@1.0.2
```

It's now working perfectly fine. I suppose the latest version is incompatible.